# represent $Im(g \circ f)$ using set logic

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to represent the above notation, Im(gºf), as a set, something like $$Im(gºf) = Im(g) - \{g(f(x)) \mid \neg(f(x))\}$$
But it seems obviously wrong. Can I say that a function is false when it is undetermined? How to use this notation "|" properly? I'm really confused.

ps: I want to know if it is possible to get a set with the elements of $Im(f)$ that cannot be in $D(gºf)$

Comment: See [Image of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Image_of_a_function): are you meaning the image of $(g \circ f) [X]$ of the entire domain $X$ of $g \circ f$ ?

Comment: If so, in general: $Im(f) = \{ y \mid \exists x \in X \ (y=f(x)) \}$.

Comment: by the way, you can make the divider used in set-builder notation by using `\mid`.  as in $\{m\mid m \lt q\}$ (just an example of what the formatting looks like in some random set which means:) "the set of all $m$ *such that* m\lt q",

Comment: $\text{Im}(g\circ f) = \text {Im}(g(f(x))$.

Comment: Did you want to write $g\circ f$ `$g\circ f$`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation for Set-builder notation.

For functions $f : A \rightarrow B$, $g : B \rightarrow C$,

$\textrm{Im}(g\circ f) = \{g\circ f(x) \,|\, x \in A\}$

'$|$' just simply means 'such that'. Written like this, the set is interpreted as 'the set containing all $g\circ f(x)$ such that $x$ is a member of $A$.

'$|$' has nothing to do with the logical 'or' in this case. You cannot say a function is 'false' when it is undefined at a point.

Comment: there is a example in the link you posted, $$ \{a \in R \mid (\exists p \in Z)(\exists q \in Z)[q\neq0 \wedge aq=p]\} $$. This is the same as $ \{a \in R \mid (\exists p \in Z)\wedge(\exists q \in Z)[q\neq0 \wedge aq=p]\} $?

Comment: @CarlosOliveira $\land$ is a logical 'and', so yes.

Comment: thank you, I didn't know that it could be omitted. Are there more cases like it?

Comment: Is true $Im(gºf) = \{x \in Im(g) \mid x = g(k) [k \in (Im(f) \cap D(g))]\}$?If it is, it is just what I needed.

Comment: @CarlosOliveira I can't be 100% sure, but I think so. Best to ask a new question to get another opinion on it imo. Including the context on what you're trying to do would also help.